# How to filter properties by access modifier

Tags: php, class, object, access-modifiers

So I would like to output the properties that are public only from within an class.

```
class MyClass
{
    $public $var1, $var2, var3;
    $private $pVar1, $pVar2, pVar3;

    //outputs all variables and their values
    //lets assume they are all defined
    function outputPublic()
    {
        foreach($this as $key=>$val)
            echo $key . ' : ' . $val . '<br>';
    }
}
```

I've got this working by using an external function to cycle through an instance of the class but I want to know how to do this from inside.
Is there a way to get the access modifier?

example of retrieving public properties externally

```
$obj = new MyClass();
foreach($obj as $key=$val)
    echo $key . ' : ' . $val;
```

Comment: Have a look at phps `ReflectionClass`

Comment: @Daan,  thanks will have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different way. You can use [get_object_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)

```
foreach(call_user_func('get_object_vars', $this) as $key => $val) {
    echo $key . ' : ' . $val . '<br>';
}
```

or you can use [ReflectionClass](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php)

```
$reflect = new ReflectionClass($this);
foreach($reflect->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC) as $props) {
    echo $props->getName() . ' : ' . $props->getValue($this) . '<br>';
}
```

I recommend using ReflectionClass instead of get_object_vars, which from php  7 you get another behavior.